create a sequence in function or procedure , if that does not exist, however if exist return the nextval
execute immediate 'select ' || p_table_name ||
                  '_id_dynamic_seq.nextval from dual'
  into v_id;
exception
when others then
  execute immediate 'create sequence ' || p_table_name ||
                    '_id_dynamic_seq';
  execute immediate 'select ' || p_table_name ||
                    '_id_dynamic_seq.nextval from dual'
    into v_id;
end;
--`asdas`
return v_id;`that us `


Littlefoot's answer is fine, but this does seem an unnecessary amount of complexity. An IDENTITY column is probably fine, but even if not, presumably at some point you are running DDL to create table - why not just create the sequence THEN

Why would you be using dynamic SQL for any of this? This shouldn't be done in PL/SQL at all. In most systems, you should create objects at time of deployment, not during execution. If you do have a legit need to dynamically create dictionary objects like this (and there are a few situations where it might make sense), query the dictionary first then create if needed, rather than using exception handlers. Exception handlers should be handling exceptions/abnormal situations only, not expected code branches.

It looks as if you want to use sequence-per-table (at least, that's what p_table_name - probably a parameter name - suggests). If that's so, and if you want to use it for primary key column's value, why wouldn't you use an identity column and let Oracle take care about it? It'll create a sequence in the background.

Anyway, here's one option. I'll use Scott's sample schema, its dept table as a parameter value.
First, let's check whether such a sequence already exists (it does not):
SQL> select dept_id_dynamic_seq.nextval from dual;
select dept_id_dynamic_seq.nextval from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Here's a function; read comments within code:
SQL> create or replace function f_seq (p_table_name in user_tables.table_name%type)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    -- sanitize input value to avoid SQL injection
  5    l_table_name user_tables.table_name%type := dbms_assert.sql_object_name(p_table_name);
  6    -- as you can't run DDL in a SELECT statement:
  7    pragma       autonomous_transaction;
  8
  9    -- catch non-existent sequence error:
 10    no_such_seq  exception;
 11    pragma       exception_init (no_such_seq, -2289);
 12
 13    -- SQL statement is composed into this variable
 14    l_str        varchar2(500);
 15
 16    -- value returned by the function
 17    retval       number;
 18  begin
 19    -- try to fetch from the sequence; if it exists, RETURN will return its next
 20    -- value. If it doesn't exist, exception will be raised
 21    l_str := 'select ' || p_table_name || '_id_dynamic_seq.nextval from dual';
 22    execute immediate l_str into retval;
 23    return retval;
 24
 25  exception
 26    when no_such_seq then
 27      -- no such sequence, so - create it:
 28      l_str := 'create sequence ' || p_table_name || '_id_dynamic_seq';
 29      execute immediate l_str;
 30
 31      -- repeat code from above, i.e. fetch from the sequence and return its value
 32      l_str := 'select ' || p_table_name || '_id_dynamic_seq.nextval from dual';
 33      execute immediate l_str into retval;
 34      return retval;
 35  end;
 36  /

Function created.

Let's test it:
SQL> select f_seq('dept') From dual;

F_SEQ('DEPT')
-------------
            1

SQL> select f_seq('dept') From dual;

F_SEQ('DEPT')
-------------
            2

Does usual way of selecting the value work? Yes, now it works:
SQL> select dept_id_dynamic_seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         3

SQL>

